# Show that there is no simple group of order $6\cdot{p}^m$ for any prime $p$ and positive integer $m$

Tags: group-theory

> Show that there is no simple group of order $6\cdot{p}^m$ for any prime $p$ and positive integer $m$.

Hi.
Basically, I have no idea how to do this. My house got flooded in the UK floods last week so I've had no time to look at this question, and I have 2 more deadlines and an exam this week. I've spent about three hours reading through my notes trying to get a start on this and it's been futile. Can someone please please help me, if I can't do this question I'll fail my coursework and I need to pass.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean $\;|G|=p^m\cdot 6=6p^m\;$ ? Because if you did you can use that a group of order $\;2m\;,\;\;m\;$ an odd number, has a *normal* subgroup of index two...

Comment: (iii) Show that there is no simple group of order p^m · 6 , for any prime p and positive integer m . Is how it is written so I assume thats 6p^m.

Comment: That doesn't **really** my question to you, @Emily: what's the problem with answering with a simple "yes" or "no"?!\

Comment: You **really** should learn by now how to properly type mathematics in this site, otherwise things can get blurry.

Comment: I was just double checking in my notes before I gave you a definite answer as I wondered why my lecturer went to the hassle of writing the 6 and p separately.

Comment: Not only separatedly, @Emily: the number to the right of the parameter. It also wasn't completely clear, until your last comment, whether you meant $\;p^m6\;$ or $\;p^{m6}\;$ ...

Comment: Anyway, my very first comment still applies for $\;6p^m\;$ (for a power of a prime the question is trivial **if** one knows a little about those groups' center, say)

Comment: oh yes I can see that now I will edit that in the question

Comment: is it if the groups centre is trivial?

Comment: What "is it", Emily? A finite $\;p$- group always has a non-trivial  center.

Comment: oh, I found "If we suppose otherwise we can assume that p ̸= 5 since a group of prime power order has a non-trivial center, and so is not simple. " in my lecture notes and thought it might help with the question.

Comment: By the way, you need to consider the case $p=2$ separately.

Answer (score 0):

Go through each one of the primes,

for $p=2$ and $p=3$ you will get $p^{m+1}.(6/p)$

Use the theorem that for any group of order $p^mb$  then G is simple if $\left\vert G \right\vert \mid b!$ and $p^m | (b-1)!$

that works for all cases apart from for $p=5$, for which you can count elements using Sylow subgroups and you will have too many.

for $p \geq 7$ it is simple that $p \nmid 5!$